# Android Studio alt + enter not working for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, enter, alt

Why it's not showing anything after selecting the widget and clicking alt + enter ? As an example to wrap a widget or to convert stateless to state full

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you have already wrapped a widget with Alt + Enter and the boundary around the Widget name is still there. You have to first type something out of that box and then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens even if you just create a widget from the stl or stf command, it takes few seconds after pressing repeatedly. I think it's a Flutter Plugin issue, because it happens on both IntelliJ and Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android Studio => Preferences => Editor => Intentions. Click *quick assists powered*

[image: Android Studio => Preferences => Editor => Intentions || Click quick assists powered....]